# Does lightning release the same electromagnetic emmisions as an arc welder?

Tags: lightning

Looking at an arc welder is bad, it is a source that emits on a broad range of the electromagnetic spectrum. More specifically the blue and UV are particularly bad for vision:

> Artificial sources of UV radiation also cause corneal damage. Injury
>   from a welder's arc commonly is known as flash burn, welder's flash,
>   or arc eye. Other sources of UV radiation injury include sun tanning
>   beds, carbon arcs, photographic flood lamps, lightning, electric
>   sparks, and halogen desk lamps. Several outbreaks of ultraviolet
>   keratitis have been observed in the United States after installation
>   of improper lighting in school gymnasiums, resulting in high levels of
>   UV radiation.

Source: https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/799025-overview

Does lightning release the same magnitude of electromagnetic emissions as an arc wielder, in UVA, UVB or UVC spectra? Could watching lightning repeatedly degrade human vision?

Comment: Voting to close, this is health related. Not related to earth sciences.

Comment: Fine I'll change it

Comment: I didn't see the original question as being too non Earth Science to stay.  It's hard to find a home for such cross-disciplinary questions.  I'm not sure whether anyone around here will be able to answer the full question about the eye dangers, but it's an interesting question :)

Comment: More like a plasma cutter.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271211/why-is-the-color-of-lightning-white-or-blue-rather-than-nothing

Comment: Voting to leave open, as it's fundemenatally asking about the spectrum of the light from lightning - which is very much on topic. The final sentence could possibly be removed from the question to remove doubt...